# Nginx returns 404 on a POST .js request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, post, nginx

I've got a Rails app that must send an POST .js request, but Nginx raise a 404 error on a POST request to `something.js`

I found out it came from my config file

```
  location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
    access_log        off;
    expires max;
  }
```

I tried to modify it this way (look at the `location` )

```
 location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
    access_log        off;
    expires max;
  }
```

And according to [Nginx raises 404 when using format => 'js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737314/nginx-raises-404-when-using-format-js), i also tried this :

```
  location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
    access_log        off;
    expires max;
    break;
  }
```

But none of the previous configuration worked out.

Thank you per advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This nginx config should only apply to static JS (and CSS files), *not* to your Rails actions.

In this case you try to post to a static file, which obviously does not exist.

All your assets (including CSS and JS files) will be in `public/assets`.

I successfully use this configuration:

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
  expires max;
  break;
}
```